# Focus item listview on Android dosent work

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, focus

I searched lot on internet to find a solution for my problem but I haven't found a answer. I hope someone can help me.

I have a Android application where I made a fragment with 3 tabs. Every tab had a different layout and in every layout there is a listview with different id. The problem is that, when i click on item of listview, only the item of the first tab take focus and background was set to green. In the other tabs the item is selected but focus don't change the background item color.
I had clear the focus on the first tab if was selected but this don't resolve the problem.

this is the code that I implementer on tab

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); 
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                selectedBusiness = businessList.get(pos);
                buttonModify.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Any idea?

Thank Max

Comment: Can you post your adapter??

Comment: It's a simple arrayadapter of string  

[code] 

ArrayList<String> businessNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < businessList.size(); i++){
     businessNames.add(businessList.get(i).getName());
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.my_business_item);

[code]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The error in my case was made from

`ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.my_business_item);`

I don't know why but the problem was the layout. In the other two tabs, I used the adapter with another layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. With this layout the focus dosen't work. With my simple layout it works.